# TV Show episode with a psychic baby looking for a father

Tags: story-identification, tv, mind-control

I was reading [Sword and sorcery short story with a wizard carrying an infant in a backpack that actually is a parasite](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225784/sword-and-sorcery-short-story-with-a-wizard-carrying-an-infant-in-a-backpack-tha) and it brought back a vague memory of watching a TV show where something happens, giving some people powers, mostly teenagers. The world isn't greatly changed by these powers, I think in part because few people actually have them. A particular set of teenagers are working at a school together, bonded together, in part, by their shared powers, which escape me for the moment. A teenage girl arrives with her baby, and it seems she has some form of mind control that lets her enthrall the boys of the group, except that it turns out that it's the baby who has the power of mind control, and is blindly seeking out a father. I want to say the episode has the baby's thoughts voiced to the audience near the end, and it's simply, "Dada?" or something similarly infantile.

The show was in English, viewed more than 5 years ago, maybe up to 20 years ago in early 2000, and I have a vague idea that I watched it either via downloaded torrents or DVD box sets from the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like it is probably [season 1 episode 5 of *Misfits*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1553999/?ref_=ttep_ep5) (2009).

> After having sex with Alisha whilst Sam is looking for him, Curtis eventually sorts things out so that Alisha is his only girlfriend. Nathan abducts a baby called Finn to the horror of his friends. Due to the storm Finn, who lives with his single parent mother Rebecca, has acquired powers that convince Nathan that the child needs a father - him. However Nathan eventually reconciles Rebecca with Finn's father. Sally, now convinced the kids were responsible for killing Tony, starts dating Simon.

---

Found by Googling `tv show about teenager with powers "baby" "mind control" seeking father` which brought up this [Den of Geek](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/believe/29814/25-super-powered-kids-on-geek-tv) page with the description:

> This super-powered baby appeared in the fifth episode of Misfits’ first series, using his power on Nathan (Robert Sheehan). Finn’s special ability, caused by the electrical storm that bestowed powers on the entire Misfits gang, is a rather sad one, inspired as it is by his real father having abandoned him. His story probably has a happy ending though, as it’s suggested he was about to be reunited with his real dad, which is probably for the best considering Nathan wasn’t really dad material.

Comment: Clunky search terms I know...